# Interaction in classes. ActionScript 3

Tags: class, actionscript-3

I have 4 ActonScript3 files: Core.as, Console.as and Globals.as.
**Note, that this structure is not necessary. Logic below is more important.**

- Core - main class.
- Console - extends MovieClip in library;
- Globals - contains variables and functions **to use anywhere**.

Globals contains:

- Array `globalArray`.
- Function `globalWriter()`, which writes/rewrites
  `globalArray`.

**`globalWriter()` must call `Report()` and `globalReader()` below.**

Console contains:

- Function `globalReader()`, which reads `globalArray` (and manipulates its class functions and vars).
- Function `Report()` (which manipulates its class functions and vars).

Core must call functions `Report()`, `globalWriter()`.

How to make this logic and how to do it right?

**UPDATE:**

In my case, I just need right declaration of all things above.

Comment: We have no idea. Show the actual classes, you can omit all the function bodies but at least the `class` and `function` declarations.

Comment: In it's current state, this question isn't a very good fit for StackOverflow as all answers will be opinion based (since there is nothing specific to work with and "doing it right" is a matter opinion).   Consider changing your question to show what you've actually tried or want, and asking for drawbacks or efficiency. Or, if what you've tried isn't working well, show it and explain your issue with it.

Comment: If you come up with a logic that you can't implement yourself then that logic is wrong to start with. It's like coming up with a new numerical system except that you don't know to to perform a simple addition, so give it up and come up with one you understand.